# Return response to client before running event Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

Is there an less ugly way to do this:

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);

ob_start();
echo $response; // send the response
header('Connection: close');
header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length());
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();
```

in Laravel? Basically i need the server to return response to user before running the events, I can't do this using queue because there's a lot of things that will be done, and a lot of clients simultaneously doing this action and those things need to be done instantly, so they can't be executed one by one. The events consist in sending mails, alerts, updating data on website tables, etc.

Comment: How are you responding? through API/Web/Console? Give a little bit more of context. Btw, to respond to users before completing your tasks, make use of [Queued Jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues). This way, you can continue doing your thing whike your server proccess your jobs in the background (like sending emails, a delayed operation).

Comment: Can you give some context around what problem you're trying to solve? From the title I might suggest terminable middleware or queued jobs, but it's not clear from the question what you're trying to achieve. (Also, headers always need to be sent before the response body)

Comment: @TravisBritz Terminable Middleware is an option, I'll search exactly how it works. I'm not sure why its not clear, i need the event to keep running after client got his response, those events will fire emails for multiple users, send alerts and table updates trough socket and other calculations to save information on the DB, but client can't wait all those things, also i cant put it com queue because it would be done 1 per 1, but i need those scripts to run multiple times on the server simultaneously.

Comment: Are you actually using Laravel's built-in event dispatcher? If so, you can also add `implements ShouldQueue` to your event listener class and Laravel will automatically use the job queue instead of immediately running the listener.

Comment: Yes, I read the question. "I can't use the queue" isn't specific; why can't some actions like sending emails and alerts be queued? There are many ways to implement an event/listener system, but which options have been explored and ruled out? Does your event have multiple listeners, and can specific ones be queued? I'm just trying to get a better understanding of how your system is structured because the answer, as always, is "it depends".

Comment: Despite your assertions to the contrary, i still think queues are the way to handle this. If you need the work to start immediately, then you simply add more queue listeners. If your workload is really unpredictable, and you get more requests than the maximum number of listeners your server can handle, then there will be a delay, but this is preferable to your proposed solution, where you would just hang your webserver. With queues you also have the option to run the listeners on a separate server

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar need in a project where I was creating a tracking pixel. I wanted to immediately return a response to them and then Laravel continue running.  I put this as the very first thing in `index.php`:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/pixel'){
    require "pixel.php";
}
```

Then in that file (some of this may not be relevant to you, i needed to make sure they didnt cache it so it continues to load the pixel:

```
ignore_user_abort(true);

// turn off gzip compression
if ( function_exists( 'apache_setenv' ) ) {
    apache_setenv( 'no-gzip', 1 );
}

ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);

// turn on output buffering if necessary
if (ob_get_level() == 0) {
    ob_start();
}

// removing any content encoding like gzip etc.
header('Content-encoding: none', true);
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    echo ' ';
} else {
    header("Content-type: image/gif");
    header("Content-Length: 42");
    header("Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-cache=Set-Cookie, proxy-revalidate");
    header("Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 2000 12:59:00 GMT");
    header("Last-Modified: Wed, 11 Jan 2006 12:59:00 GMT");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    echo sprintf('%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%',71,73,70,56,57,97,1,0,1,0,128,255,0,192,192,192,0,0,0,33,249,4,1,0,0,0,0,44,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,2,2,68,1,0,59);
}

// flush all output buffers. No reason to make the user wait for OWA.
ob_flush();
flush();
ob_end_flush();
```

That's it.  Now, Laravel continues to run, but the user's browser has ended its request.  So then I added a route like normal at `/pixel` and did all of the stuff I needed to do (add to database, fire events, etc).